# How to use Drupal.behaviors in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have these codes in my druapl 7 theme js file (js/test.js):

```
 (function($) {
    alert("Hi");
    Drupal.behaviors.mythemename = {
      attach: function(context, settings) { 
        alert("Bye");
      }
    }; 

 })(jQuery);
```

then I call this file using :

```
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename'). '/js/test.js');
```

in page--front.tpl.php file inside the theme folder.

But only the first alert is shown.
Why is it so? where is my problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably to late to load the js file in the .tpl try in template.php with

```
YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mythemename'). '/js/test.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pan, But the problem was something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved my problem. I have to use drupal_add_js in this way:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'bitcont') . '/js/s3.js', array( 
  'scope' => 'footer', 
  'weight' => '15' 
));
```